# Using jquery to add input fields

Tags: jquery

1. Newbie here with jquery
2. I would like to add a couple of input fields to a form I have already created
3. Reason is - in case a new user wants to add new degree to the one already in the database
4. This is my jquery code

   `$("#addinst").click(function(){
    $("mainform").append("<p>
    <label align="left">Institution #1:</label>
    <input name="EdInstitutionName1" type="text" value="" size="70" maxlength="100" />
    </p>");`
5. This is part of the form the form

   `<form id="someform" >
   <fieldset id="mainField">
   <p><label align="left">Institution #1:</label>
   input name="EdInstitutionName1" type="text" value="" size="70" maxlength="100" />
   tr>
   td align="left">City, State #1:</td>
   td><input name="EdInstitutionLocation1" type="text" value="" size="70" maxlength="100" /></td>
   </tr>`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that inside of your jQuery code, you are missing the `id` of the form.  To select your form, use:

`$('#mainform').append`

instead of

`$('mainform').append`

In jQuery, `ids` need to have a `#` in front of them.  Without a `#` symbol, jQuery looks for tags with that name.  Similarly, classes are selected using `.` in front of the class name.

For more information about jQuery selectors, you can refer to [the jQuery selector API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Thanks Kyle, here is my fiddle link for clarity. http://jsfiddle.net/koba/58tmm/2/ The idea is to create 5 new input fields to add another institution, I have it trying to insert a field first for test, but nothing appears to be working

Comment: @koba In your fiddle, you don't have anything with an id of `mainform`.  I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58tmm/6/